# How can I transform proportions to percentages using the forest function in R?

Tags: r, transform, percentage

This forest plot is giving me proportions. How can I transform those proportions into percentages?

```
forest(meta.MAPO.Threshold, colgap.forest.left = "1cm", layout = "RevMan5", col.study = "black", comb.fixed = FALSE, xlim = c(0.00,1.00), digits = 3, cvar = SC.O, col.by = "black")
```

I tried the following suggested by another R post (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123840/meta-analysis-transform-forest-graph-output-to-percentage-effect-in-r-metafor), but it didn't work. **Edit**: There's no error message when I use the below code. Unfortunately, there's no change to the units of the forest plot. That is, it's still showing me proportions, and not the percentages.

```
mytransf = function(x)
(x) * 100

forest(meta.MAPO.Threshold, colgap.forest.left = "1cm", layout = "RevMan5", col.study = "black", comb.fixed = FALSE, xlim = c(0.00,1.00), digits = 3, cvar = SC.O, col.by = "black",
atransf = mytransf)
```

Here's a link to a screenshot of what I currently have (it's all stated in proportions; I need to transform this into percentages):
[Forest plot with proportions (need to change these into percentages!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLGhs.png)

Comment: What did you mean 'didn't work'? can you post the error message?

Comment: Hey David. There's no error message. When I plot the forest plot again, I get the exact same thing that I'm usually getting, which is the plot with the proportions. For some reason that I don't understand, the forest plot is not transforming those proportions into percentages. :(

Comment: Argument `atransf` is for the `forest()` function of the `metafor` package, but you are using the `forest()` function of the `meta` package.

Comment: Thank you so much @Wolfgang . This point that you made finally led me to conduct the transformation using the right package. Appreciate your help!