# Meta analysis: transform forest plot output to percentage

Tags: r, percentage, metafor

I am a new R user. I am trying to transform proportions to percentages on a forest plot I have generated using metaprop.

I have looked here [Quick question about transforming proportions to percentages - forest function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67375595/quick-question-about-transforming-proportions-to-percentages-forest-function-i)  and at the link this post refers to.

```
mytransf = function(x)
  (x) * 100

studies <- c("Study 1", "Study 2", "Study 3")
obs <- c(104, 101,79670)
denom <- c(1146, 2613, 147766)
m1 <- metaprop(obs, denom, studies, comb.random=FALSE,  
               byseparator=": ")
forest(m1, print.tau2 = FALSE, col.by="black", text.fixed = "Total number of events",
       text.fixed.w = "Subtotal", rightcols = c("effect","ci"), 
       leftlabs=c("Study","Events","Total"), 
       xlim=c(0,0.7), 
       transf=mytransf)
```

The output is remains as proportions, not as percentages. I tried "atransf" as well. Is anyone able to please help me with this? This is what I can generate currently: [picture of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHsYS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pscale` option of `metaprop`:

```
library(meta)

studies <- c("Study 1", "Study 2", "Study 3")
obs <- c(104, 101,79670)
denom <- c(1146, 2613, 147766)
m1 <- metaprop(obs, denom, studies, comb.random=FALSE,  
               byseparator=": ",
               pscale=100)

forest(m1, print.tau2 = FALSE, col.by="black", 
       text.fixed = "Total number of events",
       text.fixed.w = "Subtotal", 
       rightlabs = c("Prop. (%)","[95% CI]"), 
       leftlabs=c("Study","Events","Total"), 
       xlim=c(0,70))
```

[image]